# Make coordinate assignments in a data frame in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have read in a CSV file in R and want to change one cell in it.  Below is the basic idea behind something I've tried, which I found on a website but doesn't work for me.

```
data <- read.csv('file.csv')
data[1, 2 := 3]
```

I've also tried guessing that the way to do it is,

```
data[1,2] = 3
```

or

```
data[1,2] <- 3
```

But those don't work either and my googling hasn't turned up anything else, but perhaps I just don't know what to google here.  (Tried "coordinate assignment r" and a similar things.)

With this code, suppose that the file referenced above by 'file.csv' had the following entries:

```
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5
```

I would want to read this into the variable `data` and run a command so that when I print `data` it reads

```
0, 3, 2
3, 4, 5
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and desired result.

Comment: data[1,2] <- 3 should to that. Maybe try to convert to a matrix instead of a data.frame.

Comment: if `data[1,2] <- 3` isn't working, there's probably something strange about `data`. Try posting the output from `str(data)`

Comment: Does your csv file have a header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> x <- matrix(c(0,3,1,4,2,5),2,3)
> write.table(x, "data.csv", row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE,sep=", ")
> data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=FALSE)
> data
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  1  2
2  3  4  5
> data[1,2] <- 3
> data
  V1 V2 V3
1  0  3  2
2  3  4  5
```